# Rotate column B, C, etc values based on values in column A

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm aware in Python pandas you can do `melt` to rotate cell values.

Here I want to rotate column B and C values based on column A:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

I need this to update on the fly as I change other values in the Google sheet, otherwise, I'd export this to a pandas dataframe and melt from there.

How can I "melt" in Google Sheets such that this rotation will update on the fly? If there's no built-in function, how would I do this in Google Sheets javascript?

---

Note: `Transpose` (`=TRANSPOSE(A2:C2)`) seems promising, but it doesn't pivot the table, it only moves the cell values in B and C beneath A:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B1:C<>"", "♠"&A1:A&"♦"&B1:C, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♠")), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: What are the cards symbols used for? Or are you just using them because they're very uncommon encoded characters useful for splitting?

Comment: @Growler yeah, indeed. it's used as a unique symbol

Answer (score 1):

[Example on Sheets.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wwl0eaj6EnN1UMam4Gs9OSHDq1QeLwC71eTqpJhBqPE/edit?usp=sharing)

[screenshot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12NGJ.png)

Row 1 contains "hello world" "stringA" "stringB" etc. in columns A,B,C, etc.

I'm starting the output at row 3. (Outputs to columns A, B, starting on row 3.)

You can use transpose in the second column, e.g. place your transpose in B3 like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(B1:1)
```

And then your static value for column A can be achieved with this in A3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(NOT(ISBLANK(B3:B)),$A$1,""))
```

which says to keep on eye on column B, starting at row 3, and add the static value from A1 if there is something in column B.

This dynamically grows the vertical list as you add values in row 1, and the static value follows the value of A1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the typical join split combo

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A2&""&TRANSPOSE(B2:C2),""))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but there's going to be many more rows. So changing it to navigate for each instance, i.e., `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(I2:I&"^"&TRANSPOSE(K2:L),"^"))`, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
={{A1:A2,B1:B2};{A1:A2,C1:C2};{A1:A2,D1:D2}}
```

Add as many columns in this array. I have assumed the data to have 4 columns, with column A being the leading column.

[snapshot of the data and the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBTEv.png)